# How to create a public/private key for AWS S3 to be used as SFMC File Location

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I was trying to setup FTP folder in SFMC File Locations. In location type I found AWS S3. I was all excited, as this was my end goal. I did not want to write another automation to move from FTP to S3, however to configure it I must provide a Public/Private Key. Role ARN I can obtain from AWS, but as far as I know, public/private keys are only used to SSH into a machine and not S3. All I get from AWS is a pair of access-key-id and secret-access-key.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same question, wondering if you've had any resolutions into this?

Comment: I have copied your question to the Salesforce StackExchange platform since it's more suited for this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/361067/how-to-create-a-public-private-key-for-aws-s3-to-be-used-as-sfmc-file-location